# Do you know what this shape format is?

Tags: format, maps, shapes, arcgis

I want to use some [ArcGIS extension functions](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotnet/index.htm#geodatabases/st_contains.htm) in PostgreSQL to compare shapes of buildings to shapes of areas, however, I have in my database shapes stored under forms like this:

```
240000000100000001000400020000000C00000001000000ACA289C6EC14AD8D95F6D811
```

I have no idea of what it is! Perhaps there is a way to convert it to something like:

```
polygon ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))
```

which can be handled by the `[sde.st_contains][2]` function I wan to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a binary representation of the shape to me. Try something like this:

SELECT ST_AsText(shape) FROM table;